# Print only what is exclusive to a file compared to another in Bash

Tags: files, diff, comm

Good day everyone,

I know there are a lot of similar questions already answered, but I can't find a satisfying answer and it drives me nuts.

I have two files which both contain hostnames : one that holds all the ones opened to the Internet, the other logs all the scan results of ALL our hosts, opened to Internet or not.

File A (1111.com,1112.com,www.1113.com,1114.com)

File B (1111.com,1199.com,1299.com,www2.1329.com)

My goal is to print a file that would print ONLY the hosts that are **exclusively** in file B. I tried diff and comm but I cannot presort the files, as the entries a sometimes a little bit different.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not being able to presort the files isn’t a problem:

```
comm -13 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
```

This gives

```
1199.com
1299.com
www2.1329.com
```

with your examples, assuming each host is on a separate line. `-13` tells `comm` to drop column 1 (lines unique to the first file) and 3 (lines common to both files), leaving only lines unique to the second file.

Comment: I just tried you solution and it works perfectly ! Much more readable than diff and exactly what I needed, thank you very much !